# How do I move the search bar to the top without hiding it?

Tags: html, css, position

In this website [www.johnpaulus.com](http://www.johnpaulus.com) I am unable to move the top search bar to the topmost position, just to the right of the social networking icons. It is getting hidden behind the background.

How can I shift it up and make it visible on the right side of the social networking icons?

I wish to use CSS / HTML only.

Comment: Please include the relevant code here instead of linking to an external site. If the external site changes or goes away, this question then loses context and becomes useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your positioning is wrong, a fiddle would be helpful but just did this using firebug, give `margin: -40px 0 0;` to `#searchbar`, you can do it better with positioning but as you've not shared any fiddle or code I tried to modify your styles

Screen Shot

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked :) I wonder why it went hidden behind the background previously, but I don't remember the code I used.